# How to extract X509 Certificate fields in Java

Tags: java, cryptography, x509certificate

I am currently working on an application that will process certain fields of a X509 Certificate, and I cannot seem to figure out how to extract certain parts of the certificate for debugging purposes. So far I have only been able to figure out how to read a certificate from a file based on the Javadoc for java.security.cert.Certificate, using this code:

```
FileInputStream fis = new FileInputStream(filename);
BufferedInputStream bis = new BufferedInputStream(fis);

CertificateFactory cf = CertificateFactory.getInstance("X.509");
while (bis.available() > 0) {
    Certificate cert = cf.generateCertificate(bis);
System.out.println(cert.toString());
}
```

Assuming that no exceptions are thrown, and that cert is a valid certificate, how would I do this?

*Sidenote* I am using Bouncy Castle in this project

Comment: `available()` is not a test for end of stream. You should use [`generateCertificates()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/security/cert/CertificateFactory.html#generateCertificates-java.io.InputStream-) in this case.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Cast it to an `X509Certificate`:

```
X509Certificate cert = (X509Certificate) cf.generateCertificate(bis);
System.out.println(cert.getSubjectDN());
```