# Java: How to check whether a certificate is self-signed

Tags: java, security, certificate

Looking for a direct way how to check whether a certificate is self-signed (not self-issued).

The certificate don't have the *Authority* and *Subject* Key Identifiers.

From this answer (https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/93162/how-to-know-if-certificate-is-self-signed), it is possible to check it via openssl command:

```
openssl verify -CAfile /cert/to/check.pem /cert/to/check.pem
```

I need to check it in the simplest way possible, probably with java.security package. Is this even possible?

Comment: The linked question/answer contains the [solution](https://security.stackexchange.com/a/93163/1204). Have you tried to just read the certificate? See e.g. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41113139/how-to-extract-x509-certificate-fields-in-java

Comment: The solution is not right, self-issued != self-signed. See the follow up comments & posts.